# How would I write a batch file which will name files in a directory like Windows Explorer auto rename?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

In windows explorar we can select multiple files in a folder and rename them sequally, but I want to do the same thing with batch skript

change this

```
     A.mp4
     B.mp4  
     C.mp4
     DD.mp4
```

to this

```
     (1).mp4
     (2).mp4   
     (3).mp4
     (4).mp4
```

Comment: Not tested a single command line version: `@set "FileNumber=1" & @for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do @set "FileName=%%I" & @setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & @ren "!FileName!" "(!FileNumber!).mp4" & @endlocal & @set /A FileNumber+=1` Questions like your once are asked and answered already multiple times. So please use the Stack Overflow search at top, for example with [\[batch-file\] increment* number file name](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+increment*+number+file+name). It is not possible to write a multi-line code in a comment.

Comment: use a renaming tool, see the examples: https://github.com/75lb/renamer

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
ren C:\Path\beforefilename.mp4 afterfilename.mp4
```

Example:

```
ren C:\Path\A.mp4 (1).mp4
```

Result is
Filename A.mp4 changed to (1).mp4